# Python : List + lambda behaviour

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary in the list has the same keys but each has different values, e.g.:

```
my_list = [
  {key1: 100, key2: 110, key3: 120},
  {key1: 200, key2: 210, key3: 220},
  {key1: 300, key2: 310, key3: 320}]
```

I used the following to replace `key2` with a new key `new_key2`:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.update({"new_key2": x.pop("key2")}), my_list))
```

The code works and `my_list` is updated correctly, but I cannot understand the following behavior:

```
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x.update({"new_key2" : x.pop ("key2")}), my_list))
```

In this case `my_list` returned the following values:

```
my_list[0] = None
my_list[1] = None
my_list[2] = None
```

Why? Shouldn't 'list + map' functions retrieve me a list?

Comment: Your lambda function isnt returning any values it just updates the list

Comment: What do you want your list to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of an `update` statement is `None`, hence why the returned result is `[None, None, None]`.  There is no need to call `list` on the `map` function.  This function is updating each item in `mylist` inplace.

I believe the following code is more pythonic and also handles the case when there is no `key2`.  The variable `mylist` is modified inplace, so there is no need to reassign it to a list.  The approach below is slightly more memory efficient compared to a reassigning the result of a list comprehension.

```
for d in mylist:
    try:
        d['new_key2'] = d.pop('key2')
    except KeyError:
        pass  # no 'key2'

>>> mylist
[{'key1': 100, 'key3': 120, 'new_key2': 110},
 {'key1': 200, 'key3': 220, 'new_key2': 210},
 {'key1': 300, 'key3': 320, 'new_key2': 310}]
```

If you prefer to use the `map` method (it is faster in this case), I'd recommend the following:

```
map(lambda x: 
    x.update({"new_key2": x.pop("key2")}) 
    if 'key2' in x else None, mylist)
```

There is no need to assign the result, as it is just a list of None values.

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda function does not return anything, it just updates the list. Look at this block of code.

```
In [15]: mylist = [
  {'key1' : 100, 'key2' : 110, 'key3' : 120},
  {'key1' : 200, 'key2' : 210, 'key3' : 220},
  {'key1' : 300, 'key2' : 310, 'key3' : 320}]

In [16]: list(map(lambda x: x.update({"mewkey2" : x.pop ("key2")}), mylist))
Out[16]: [None, None, None]

In [17]: mylist
Out[17]:
[{'key1': 100, 'key3': 120, 'mewkey2': 110},
 {'key1': 200, 'key3': 220, 'mewkey2': 210},
 {'key1': 300, 'key3': 320, 'mewkey2': 310}]
```

If you want to have a new variable corresponding to this new list, do something like

```
newlist = mylist[::]
list(map(lambda x: x.update({"mewkey2" : x.pop ("key2")}), newlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two ways to do this.  The first modifies the existing dictionaries (and returns a reference to the dictionary so you don't have to deal with `None`)

```
def replace_key(old_key, new_key, d):
    d[new_key] = d.pop('old_key')
    return d

mylist = [replace_key('key2', 'newkey2', d) for d in mylist]
```

The second is a more pure functional approach without side effects (I wouldn't recommend this for real applications, it's much less efficent)

```
mylist = [{k : v if k != 'key2' else 'newkey2': v for k, v in d.items()} for d in mylist]
```